# Creating parameter for tableName results in exception

Tags: c#, ado.net

Hi I am trying to create a generic method for reading data from the database.Here is what I have so far:

```
private static void GetData(string tableName, string key, string values)
    {
        string connectionString = "data source=DB03RO;initial catalog=NCOI_Dev;User ID=NCOI_Olympus;Password=Olympus;persist security info=False;packet size=4096;Enlist=true;Transaction Binding=Explicit Unbind;";
        string commandText = @"SELECT @key , @value FROM @Name";
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", tableName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@key", key));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value", values));
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = commandText;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader != null)
            {
                string id = (string)reader[key];
                string data = (string)reader[values];
                Console.WriteLine(id + " " + data);
            }
        }
    }
```

I seem to be getting an error when I try to Execute the reader:

> Must declare the table variable "@Name".

How can I correct this problem?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, it may be helpfull to rely on a DataAdapter (or SqlDataAdapter) to fill your table http://stackoverflow.com/a/3160328/1236044

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot substitute database objects (table, column, view etc) names with parameterized queries. You can only do it with concatenation.

```
string commandText = String.Format("SELECT {0}, {1} FROM {2}", key, value, tableName);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot parametise table names.
You'd rather just use `string.Format("SELECT @key , @value FROM [{0}]", tableName);`

although this way it will be vulnerable to sql-injections.
But I guess you're not getting the table-name from user-input, and developers in your team are not like guys who can occasionaly type `'fake]; delete everything!!!'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert in `SQL`, but, as far as I know, you can not parametrize the *name of the table* in query. You should use some other mechanism for that.

Use simple `string.Format({0}, "")` with *mandatory control of the validity of the parameter passed*

Answer (score 0):

Object names must be static in TSQL.

You would have to use `string.Format` or something similar to accomplish your goal.

Similar question: [Table name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/sql-tablename-as-variable)